# My SaaS Vendor is using a .htaccess file. I'm not sure how to use it to put in browser caching

Tags: web-services, .htaccess, iis, isapi, helicontech

The .htaccess file looks like this below. I've never really seen an .htaccess that looks like this.

Not sure what language or what code base it's using. What I would like to do is caching that looks like this:

http://gtmetrix.com/leverage-browser-caching.html

[image]

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.72

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCompatibility2 On
RepeatLimit 20
RewriteBase

#  Block external access to the httpd.ini and httpd.parse.errors files
RewriteRule ^/httpd(?:\.ini|\.parse\.errors)$ / [NC,F,O]

#  Block external access to the Helper ISAPI Extension
RewriteRule ^.*\.isrwhlp$ / [NC,F,O]

# Fix missing slash char on folders
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+[^.?/])$ $1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule /default.aspx / [r=301]

##################
# Kalio Rules #
##################

# product link, these rules handle links like: http://www.ulla.com/FriendlyUrlName/p/111
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/ /Product\.aspx\?p=$2 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Product\.aspx\?p=$2 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Product\.aspx\?p=$2&$3=$4 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Product\.aspx\?p=$2&$3=$4 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Product\.aspx\?p=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Product\.aspx\?p=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Product\.aspx\?p=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Product\.aspx\?p=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Product\.aspx\?p=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Product\.aspx\?p=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Product\.aspx\?p=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*) /Product\.aspx\?p=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [I,QSA]

# product link, these rules handle links like: http://www.ulla.com/ULLA_ULLA/FriendlyUrlName/p/111
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/ /$1/Product\.aspx\?p=$3 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Product\.aspx\?p=$3 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Product\.aspx\?p=$3&$4=$5 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Product\.aspx\?p=$3&$4=$5 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Product\.aspx\?p=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Product\.aspx\?p=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Product\.aspx\?p=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Product\.aspx\?p=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Product\.aspx\?p=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Product\.aspx\?p=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Product\.aspx\?p=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11&$12=$13 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*) /$1/Product\.aspx\?p=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11&$12=$13 [I,QSA]

# product link, these rules handle links like: http://www.ulla.com/site_admin/ULLA_ULLA/FriendlyUrlName/p/111
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Product\.aspx\?p=$4 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Product\.aspx\?p=$4 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Product\.aspx\?p=$4&$5=$6 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Product\.aspx\?p=$4&$5=$6 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Product\.aspx\?p=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Product\.aspx\?p=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Product\.aspx\?p=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Product\.aspx\?p=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Product\.aspx\?p=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Product\.aspx\?p=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Product\.aspx\?p=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12&$13=$14 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/p/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*) /$1/$2/Product\.aspx\?p=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12&$13=$14 [I,QSA]

# category link, these rules support links like: http://www.ulla.com/FriendlyUrlName/c/111
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/ /Category\.aspx\?c=$2 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Category\.aspx\?c=$2 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Category\.aspx\?c=$2&$3=$4 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Category\.aspx\?c=$2&$3=$4 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Category\.aspx\?c=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Category\.aspx\?c=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Category\.aspx\?c=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Category\.aspx\?c=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Category\.aspx\?c=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Category\.aspx\?c=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /Category\.aspx\?c=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*) /Category\.aspx\?c=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [I,QSA]

# category link, these rules support links like: http://www.ulla.com/ULLA_ULLA/FriendlyUrlName/c/111
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/ /$1/Category\.aspx\?c=$3 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Category\.aspx\?c=$3 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Category\.aspx\?c=$3&$4=$5 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Category\.aspx\?c=$3&$4=$5 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Category\.aspx\?c=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Category\.aspx\?c=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Category\.aspx\?c=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Category\.aspx\?c=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Category\.aspx\?c=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Category\.aspx\?c=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/Category\.aspx\?c=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11&$12=$13 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*) /$1/Category\.aspx\?c=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11&$12=$13 [I,QSA]

# category link, these rules support links like: http://www.ulla.com/site_admin/ULLA_ULLA/FriendlyUrlName/c/111
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Category\.aspx\?c=$4 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Category\.aspx\?c=$4 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Category\.aspx\?c=$4&$5=$6 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Category\.aspx\?c=$4&$5=$6 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Category\.aspx\?c=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Category\.aspx\?c=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Category\.aspx\?c=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Category\.aspx\?c=$$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Category\.aspx\?c=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Category\.aspx\?c=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/$2/Category\.aspx\?c=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12&$13=$14 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/c/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*) /$1/$2/Category\.aspx\?c=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12&$13=$14 [I,QSA]

# article link
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/ /article\.aspx\?a=$2 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /article\.aspx\?a=$2 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /article\.aspx\?a=$2&$3=$4 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /article\.aspx\?a=$2&$3=$4 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /article\.aspx\?a=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /article\.aspx\?a=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /article\.aspx\?a=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /article\.aspx\?a=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /article\.aspx\?a=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /article\.aspx\?a=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /article\.aspx\?a=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*) /article\.aspx\?a=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [I,QSA]

# article link, these rules support links like: http://www.ulla.com/ULLA_ULLA/FriendlyUrlName/a/111
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/ /$1/article\.aspx\?a=$3 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/article\.aspx\?a=$3 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/article\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/article\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/article\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/article\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/article\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/article\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/article\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/article\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/article\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11&$12=$13 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/a/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*) /$1/article\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11&$12=$13 [I,QSA]

# info link
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/ /info\.aspx\?i=$2 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /info\.aspx\?i=$2 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /info\.aspx\?i=$2&$3=$4 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /info\.aspx\?i=$2&$3=$4 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /info\.aspx\?i=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /info\.aspx\?i=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /info\.aspx\?i=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /info\.aspx\?i=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /info\.aspx\?i=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /info\.aspx\?i=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /info\.aspx\?i=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*) /info\.aspx\?i=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12 [I,QSA]

# info link, these rules support links like: http://www.ulla.com/ULLA_ULLA/FriendlyUrlName/i/111
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/ /$1/info\.aspx\?a=$3 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/info\.aspx\?a=$3 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/info\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/info\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/info\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/info\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/info\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/info\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/info\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/info\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /$1/info\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11&$12=$13 [I,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/i/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*) /$1/info\.aspx\?a=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9&$10=$11&$12=$13 [I,QSA]
```

Comment: What OS is it? What software is fetching this .htaccess?

Comment: @Andrew My response headers say:

Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 10639

200 OK

Comment: Ok. IIS7.5. At least it's Windows. How, which HeliconTech software is it, do you know?

Comment: @Andrew From what I'm seeing, Helicon ISAPI Rewrite. Not sure beyond that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISAPI_Rewrite does not support Browser Caching, from what I remember. HeliconApe can do this kind of things.